# VueJS Computed Data Search Not Functioning

Tags: vuejs2

I am attempting to create a search function in my Vue.js 2 application. However, even though my algorithm is giving me the right results, I am not getting the proper filter. Right now, whenever I run a search, I get nothing on the page. Here is my code:

```
computed:{
filteredSmoothies: function(){
  return this.smoothies.filter(smoothie => {
    var stuff = smoothie.title.split(" ").concat(smoothie.description.split(" ")).concat(smoothie.category)
    var sorted = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++) {
        sorted.push(stuff[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    console.log(sorted)

    if(this.search != null){
      var indivthings = this.search.split(" ")
      indivthings.forEach(item => {
        if(sorted.includes(item.toLowerCase())){console.log("true")} else {console.log("false")}
        if(sorted.includes(item.toLowerCase())){return true}
      })
    } else {
      return true
    }
  })
}
```

}

Here is my relevant HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <label for="search">Search: </label>
  <input type="text" name="search" v-model="search">
</div>
<div class="index container">
  <div class="card" v-for="smoothie in filteredSmoothies" :key="smoothie.id">
    <div class="card-content">
      <i class="material-icons delete" @click="deleteSmoothie(smoothie.id)">delete</i>
      <h2 class="indigo-text">{{ smoothie.title }}</h2>
      <p class="indigo-text">{{ smoothie.description }}</p>
      <ul class="ingredients">
        <li v-for="(ing, index) in smoothie.category" :key="index">
          <span class="chip">{{ ing }}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="btn-floating btn-large halfway-fab pink">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'EditSmoothie', params: {smoothie_slug: smoothie.slug}}">
        <i class="material-icons edit">edit</i>
      </router-link>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not trying to filter through the indivthings. I am only trying to filter through smoothies. @Sphinx

Answer (score 1):

As the discussions in the comments, the root cause should be:

you didn't return true/false apparently inside `if(this.search != null){}`, it causes `return undefined` defaultly.

So my opinion is use Javascript [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or Array.some. Also you can use **for** loop + **break** to implement the goal.

Below is one simple demo for **Array.every**.

```
computed:{
filteredSmoothies: function(){
  return this.smoothies.filter(smoothie => {
    var stuff = smoothie.title.split(" ").concat(smoothie.description.split(" ")).concat(smoothie.category)
    var sorted = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++) {
        sorted.push(stuff[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    console.log(sorted)

    if(this.search != null){
      var indivthings = this.search.split(" ")
      return !indivthings.every(item => { // if false, means item exists in sorted
        if(sorted.includes(item.toLowerCase())){return false} else {return true}
      })
    } else {
      return true
    }
  })
}
```

or you can still use forEach, the codes will be like:

```
  let result = false
  var indivthings = this.search.split(" ")
  indivthings.forEach(item => {
    if(sorted.includes(item.toLowerCase())){result = true}
  })
  return result
```

Comment: Perfect. Only change I might make is to use `Array.prototype.some()`

Comment: @Derek hah, you are right, my fever brain, forgot this API.

Comment: All good man, we all forget features at some point! Especially with how vast and dynamic JS is

Answer (score -1):

filteredSmoothies is not returning a list. You iterate over to see if indivthings is contained within sorted, but you don't do anything with that information. I think you need to modify your sorted list based on the results of indivthings.

Comment: Yes, its returning a list

Comment: ok, then whats the indivthings for? its not inside another function

Comment: Its used to iterate over each of the search items

Comment: Why would it need to be inside another function? `filter`, by its very implementation will always return a list, therefore, so will `filteredSmoothies`

Comment: ahh, ok, my bad, didn't see that it was part of the filter function

Comment: No problem! I suspect the problem has more to do with the fact that `return` inside of `indivthings` ending the iterate of the `forEach` rather than the `filter`

Comment: But we don't have enough information to truly tell. A data sample would be nice.

Comment: i think its the second if(sorted.includes(item.toLowerCase())) , there is a spurious }) after the { return true; } or a missing return false

Comment: Yeah, but if you look, its encapsulated by `forEach`, which means it only ends the execution of the current `forEach` item iteration, the enclosing `filter` is unaffected entirely

Comment: I have done a console.log test. At the beginning, it is returning a proper array, but when I insert my search terms, I am getting an empty array.

Comment: I have done a console.log test. At the beginning, it is returning a proper array, but when I insert my search terms, I am getting an empty array. @Derek

Comment: @Vicky the root cause should be you doesn't return true/false inside `if(this.search != null){}`, actually you did is return true/false inside the callback of `indivthings.forEach(}`

Comment: Oh - I understand. Thank you. How should I solve that issue? @Sphinx

Comment: @Vicky uses [Javascript Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) may be better (or uses `Array.filter` but it will loop all items). this is one simple demo: `let items1 = ['a', 'b', null]
let items2 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
let query = 'a'
function testItems(data, key) {
  let result = data.every((item) => {
    return key !== item //return false to break the loop
  })
  return !result
}
console.log('case1', testItems(items1, query))
console.log('case2', testItems(items2, query))`

Comment: @Sphinx I am having a bit of difficulty viewing your code in the comments section - could you please show me how to use it with my search algorithm and post it as an answer, because I don't exactly know where my code would fit in? I would greatly appreciate it.